# iPad linkedin SDK integration Login flow is not working

Tags: linkedin-api

I have integrated Linkedin SDK for iOS to my application for iPhone and iPad . In iPhone for login flow works perfect But for iPad when try to login with linked in from My application it is redirect to linkedin App. but after login it won't get back to My application.